# Return the datatype of a property based on entity name and property name

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to retrieve the data type of a property based on the name of an entity and name of a property; both of which are declared as a string.

Take the following entity for example

```
public class Client
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
}
```

From "Client" and "Phone" I would like "string" to be returned.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done like so:

```
System.Reflection.PropertyInfo nameProp = typeof(Client).GetProperty("Name");
Type nameType = nameProp.PropertyType; // nameType  will be System.String
```

If you don't know the exact type then use:

```
var type = Type.GetType("Namespace.ClassName, Assembly");
```

Comment: What if I am unable to declare _typeof(Client)_ and instead type is passed through as a string? _typeof("Client")_

Comment: Then type = Type.GetType("MyNamespace.MyEntity, MyEntityAssembly")

Comment: @TrystanWilcock Did my answer help with your issue?

Answer (score 0):

For `Type.GetType`, we need to pass the full name, if you prefer shortname like `Client` instead of `Namespace.Client`, you could try code below to retrive the types from assembly.

```
Assembly assembly  = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
var type = assembly.GetTypes().ToList().FirstOrDefault(t => t.Name == "Client");
System.Reflection.PropertyInfo nameProp = type.GetProperty("Name");
string typeName = nameProp.PropertyType.Name; // nameType  will be System.String
```